# How to format Orchard CMS autoroute to not display zeroes

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am new to orchard and have just started to migrate my blog (which was created from scratch). I haven't started studying on how to extend orchard and I am just looking for a solution without touching code if possible (just configuring on the admin panel would be great).

I basically just want to remove the zeroes from the url generated by autoroute. Example:

http://johnvinnymarquez.net/blog/2012/2/26/mvc-assethelper -> This is the route from my original site

http://orchard.johnvinnymarquez.net/blog/2012/02/26/mvc-assethelper -> generated form my temporary site

Comment: What are your current Autoroute settings?

Comment: {Content.Container.Path}/{Content.Date.Format:yyyy}/{Content.Date.Format:MM}/{Content.Date.Format:dd}/{Content.Slug}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use M and d instead of MM and dd in your autoroute pattern.

Comment: http://johnvinnymarquez.net/blog/2013/March%2007/3/7/2013/fitbox-technogym - this is what happened.

Comment: You can see custom date formats here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx {Content.Data.Local.Format:yyyy/M/d} should work.

Comment: its not happening: {Content.Container.Path}/{Content.Date.Format:yyyy}/{Content.Date.Format:M}/{Content.Date.Format:d}/{Content.Slug} --> The result: /blog/2012/July 04/7/4/2012/{slug}

Comment: oops, my bad. but still it generates a just a space instead of a date:  "blog/ /exam-70-486..."

Comment: I made a typo up there: it's Date, not Data. Was that the problem?